# perl replace block of text

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I'm very stuck on creating a piece of perl i need.

I have a file which contains the following

```
    define(`CONFM4_AST_MODULES', `NOLOAD => app_thingie.so
    NOLOAD => app_thingie2.so
    NOLOAD => app_thingie3.so')
```

Now i need to be able to rewrite this whole block so i was thinking on matching everything that is between  "(`CONFM4_AST_MODULES" and "')" Delete it and then append it again. on the end of the file. 
Is it possible to regex a thing like this? if so how?

It is not possible to hardcode the entire text in my perl script as it changes sometimes.

If you have any other ideas on how to solve this i love to hear it :)

also the number of thingies that exist in the file changes from 3 to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can read the whole file into a variable and do the replacement:

```
my $var = do { local $/; <> };                           # Read in the file.
my $re = qr/(define\(`CONFM4_AST_MODULES',[^)]+\)\n?)/;  # How to search for the defines.
my @defs = $var =~ /$re/g;                               # Remember the defines.
$var =~ s/$re//g;                                        # Remove them.
print $var, @defs;
```

**Updated**: Code improved and tested.

Comment: Could you explain what the "join q(), <>;" part does?
And i assume $var is already filled with the text in this example.

Comment: No, `<>` reads lines from a file, `join` creates one string from them.

Comment: @Hydrosine: I updated the code with a more traditional idiom.

Comment: It worked! only thing left is writing it out to the file but i will figure that out :) Could you please explain the Regex part some more. we looked at it with 3 persons and couldn't understand it..

Comment: After the comma, the string must match `[^)]+`, which means anything but right parenthesis at least one time. Then, `\)` matches the parenthesis and `\n?` mathes a newline if there is any. The whole thing is in `(...)` to be returned to `@defs`.

Comment: still a lot to learn about Regex! Thanks for your explanation.